# Firefox 57 closing dropdown when scrolling up or down

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, events, select

When you open a dropdown, and then scroll up/down a bit, the dropdown is getting closed. It is happening in FF 57.0.3 64 bit, but chrome looks good. This problem was not there until my FF upgraded to 57+. If you try this [example](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_select) in both browser, you will see the same problem.

I was playing around with the both browsers. I don't think this is a bug, seems like a feature specific to browsers. In Chrome they don't let you scroll when dropdown is opened. In Firefox, They let you scroll, by closing the dropdown automatically. Any idea how can I make Firefox to behave same as Chrome?

Comment: Let me know if I need to provide any more informations.

Comment: This is clear regression - why not put bug report to mozilla?

Comment: @RomanSusi Yes I [filed](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1197862) it.